# Is the result of this base64 object encrypted?

Tags: python, json, base64

I am trying to write my own interface to a webchat service. The only problem is, I can't make sense of the returns from the server. The communication towards the server is easily decoded, but I wonder if the server response is encrypted / compressed somehow. The package header specifies the result as "application/json".

Using fiddler2, I intercepted the following http package from the server:

```
vS1gN7zSnVkl7tP4+ygk4f0uJWxWH532dgLhMxYMh8dFCNfyHrkiPCtjS+TPzryHBECM3pVv90GgNI9xkLKNjR9pQ0PUpHAL2TAmRmxSbHCwmEwbDJ2WLLwMwIXdeaQWgbIxfZG5wkdH58JHqwf2FxCaGrVTidkeUDKdCBEZtnpXUoKUizpxzPB+r4KeTTc3vIMk/x/1LbIgumVWq0HEnHFGnYk2Dy1PjfiSJ+MdTus=
```

Looking at the type of code, I think it is base64 encoded. Using python I run the simple command:

```
import base64
print base64.decodestring("string above")
```

But it only returns gibberish. With repr() added to the above result, it gives back:

```
'\xbd-`7\xbc\xd2\x9dY%\xee\xd3\xf8\xfb($\xe1\xfd.%lV\x1f\x9d\xf6v\x02\xe13\x16\x0c\x87\xc7E\x08\xd7\xf2\x1e\xb9"<+cK\xe4\xcf\xce\xbc\x87\x04@\x8c\xde\x95o\xf7A\xa04\x8fq\x90\xb2\x8d\x8d\x1fiCC\xd4\xa4p\x0b\xd90&FlRlp\xb0\x98L\x1b\x0c\x9d\x96,\xbc\x0c\xc0\x85\xddy\xa4\x16\x81\xb21}\x91\xb9\xc2GG\xe7\xc2G\xab\x07\xf6\x17\x10\x9a\x1a\xb5S\x89\xd9\x1eP2\x9d\x08\x11\x19\xb6zWR\x82\x94\x8b:q\xcc\xf0~\xaf\x82\x9eM77\xbc\x83$\xff\x1f\xf5-\xb2 \xbaeV\xabA\xc4\x9cqF\x9d\x896\x0f-O\x8d\xf8\x92\'\xe3\x1dN\xeb'
```

I have tried parsing this through various version of unicode and other encoding schemes, but I can't make sense of it. Anyone have any ideas for me on how to proceed?

---

Edit: More examples:

```
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

vS1gN7zSnVkl7tP4+ygk4f0uJWxWH532dgLhMxYMh8e8M2NVwbz+GdH+VgmoGtgQJ8QEE4afjUTWunMiZ82nEWSmfxE8poUzIcYHYt6KDzSwY68OP3Cgjzoy1mjvw77STW1GSX2xv3hEp8ELucRj1RAikkHAImUELIOcW8e0lx5AS33Nv1v8PuIi6Kh+iRNjadBJ2Q2jLc0BabX2W5icJMcjtASlbVpZrtAqaAFNJ/Hr6sJfCeP5YKXpsgUrZURfcih2QXear3znFe4IKUtzbrIuvfXLAGYRrniOtnP0xcHtuQpKQD3dmPRbZJ0Od+2d4FcdUCoWCVh7xEJ1v2TnYBN1YYkDGpWRV3755H43Xg6rq2lwqo+J7E0h7beqjYaccZ4mU9BmjgQYOOhckEiQ1btrjkvt2epu5hvSXzHThuLi7ub9N10/7C6OPZ+qPFrWmRtoIeH6OMCMAUP7Vsk5m9WhSOAO+pcy+VfoHbzEI0mCVu42beNSBy3UWMUea5aBuBiWzZuVSKenTRvM4NzBKpicHBTSFwzk3zRQ32DKDwf2r9YNuKaB5eZb/VrevYFRQ3uw4MlQvZaeIplg5IR2pW0hjE9nOlgzpzYnd2MiypF3sFkLE+K69QTQcM5XhuYZg1j7Vnvjil26sB6TyABuYj9CKMj9ZK7nn2gPJekfCTU1aEAK8WMitKUrkgZJK60ezzVQqsxOpng5hPt5KhtY4wVn6GYvEUWeucbfOEq1yF5h9Y+auovEdsPVc3PJmqnifRUX+B5FjTLN05QNWGHRb1FgaydqTpA/w0jZ5LQJGcyghu6yYurYh6i+AfG00EpjgfLi9qpDD85S9u8btyS90LDj2RyVpim0f0w5bnDXnMAGAaPh9Q8O50XHbehGgGEzYS/m8iJ08c/5eyris+nPPDwv9na6jKoMoZTkauaKaKRnqLOf9ftNnGdwlyHCHjhGuuw90q5/E/fbWTWX1vzLrZJ+y3bXQcd5+m8DUoiD4tS+QS+MwbWfzeLu3PRLvA72/pI7PLOQheOccqUmvVIYKL3UVtlLdTD6lOP/mE1nKxr5DUkj43hX/9lIQC+A/4pS
```

Comment: What makes you think that this is base64?

Comment: @Blender I would think the same as well, for several reasons: 1. It uses the same character set, 2. it ends with a `=`, and 3. decoding works...

Comment: @Blender, exactly what glglgl just wrote. It looked to me to obey to all the rules involved in base64, including the "=" padding at the end.

Comment: @Stephan: Do you have any more samples of the responses? If they all have the `=` padding, then it probably is something base64-encoded.

Comment: Do you have any additional information? Which webchat service are you talking about? The data is not easily decipherable as it is.

Comment: Given that all the examples start with the same string, it's probably not encrypted (or at least, there's an unencrypted header). If it's a webchat service, you should be able to look at how the actual client code (js?) handles the incoming messages, and reverse engineer the protocol from that.

Comment: Is it possible that the "gibberish" being returned is actually the hex for Unicode or some other character set?